# Dependency has different version for the compile (x) and runtime (y)

Tags: android

i got this error

> Android dependency 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7' has different version for the compile (23.0.1) and runtime (27.0.2)

Comment: Add your gradle files to your question if you'd like a definitive answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your app level build.gradle file, upgrade target sdk and compiled sdk to 27 and all support version to 27.0.2 where error is shown.